# Using a function and an array to get the maximum and minimum value

Tags: c++

I am having some trouble getting my program to find the maximum and minimum values for a set of students GPA's. I can do this easily without using a function but when I include the function my program still runs fine but it does not calculate the maximum and minimum GPA's. I have debugged it as well and by the looks of things the program simply runs straight over it without looking at it. Your help would be greatly appreciated. This is what my code currently looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

float array(int arr[], int size)
{
    float max = 0;
    float min = 4;
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] > max)
            max = arr[i];

        if (arr[i] < min)
            min = arr[i];
    }
    cout << "Maximum GPA: " << max;
    cout << "Minimum GPA: " << min;

}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int ID[3];
    float GPA[3];
    int i;

    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please enter student ID and GPA: " << endl;
        cin >> ID[i] >> GPA[i];
        array[GPA, i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
    {
        cout << endl << "Student ID: " << ID[i] << endl << "Student GPA: " << GPA[i] << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: _"by the looks of things the program simply runs straight over it without looking at it"_ I don't understand why students keep jumping to this conclusion.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I'm wondering how his program "ran fine"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling your function wrong:

```
array[GPA, i];
```

should be

```
array(GPA, i);
```

Your code shouldn't have even compiled, since I don't see an `array` variable.

There are also a few other things wrong with your code.  `array` is probably a bad name for your function - meaningful function names are good practice, and `std::array`'s existence can cause problems.  `size` in your `array` function is unused, and as @jaggedSpire pointed out.  Your `array` function should probably be

```
void array(float arr[], int size)
```

assumming you start using `size`.

Comment: Additionally, you are not returning a value from your array function, which should return a float, and you are taking an argument of an int array type into your array function, when the array you supply it with in your function call is of a float type. (`float array(int arr[], int size)` -> `void array (float arr[], int size)`)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I am quite new to programming but I think your function call array[GPA,i]
should be array(GPA,i); and move it further down to just above return.
its my first attempt at answering a question hope it helps.